# What are these silver "sporks" for?

Tags: utensils

I was going through some miscellaneous silverware in my in-laws' drawers, and ran across a set of these strange-looking forks that look a bit like sporks.

Anyone know what specific food they're for?

[image: pair of silver "sporks"]

UPDATE: the forks in the photo are quite small, only about 5 inches long, the size of a salad fork.

Comment: I believe they are nothing more than serving forks

Comment: Ah, no, they're quite small.  I'll update the description.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming they are the same size as the other forks and spoons, they are most likely ice cream forks.

Other possibilities are a terrapin fork or a ramekin fork (both are more specialized, and possibly less fun, than an ice cream fork).

Comment: Based on a image search, ice cream fork appears to be correct.  Shame, terrapin fork would have been somewhat exciting from a "wierd antiques" perspective.  As a bonus, though, I now know that I have several Ramekin Forks in the same set; I thought they were just salad forks!

Comment: Have we been reading Miss Manners? ^_^

Comment: Actually learned about them some years ago when my uncle was talking about some of our family's silver. I did have to google for other spork-shaped utensils though (none of my ancestors had terrapin forks, lol)

Comment: Are they actually silver?  I feel like that'd be a particularly bad choice for ice cream, given how thermally conductive silver is.